# Series of numbers without 6

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let $\{n_k\}$ be the sequence of natural numbers who doesn't have the number $6$ on the decimal expansion, i.e. $\{n_k\} = \mathbb{N}\backslash\{6,16,26,36,46,56,60,61,\ldots\}$.
>
> Demonstrate that $$\sum\limits \frac{1}{n_k} = L<90$$

I'm trying to add numbers of the sequence $\{\frac{1}{n\log(n)}\}$ or $\{\frac{1}{n^2}\}$ and compare, but I'm not sure if this is working.

Comment: This is known as [Kempner series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kempner_series). For a proof that its limit $< 80$ (in the same spirit as Calvin's answer) and more infos about it, please follow above link.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Show that there are $8 \times 9^{n-1}$ $n$ digit numbers which do not contain the digit 6.

**Hint:** Use a crude geometric progression bound, and show that the sum is less than $8 \times \frac{1}{1- \frac{9}{10}} = 80$.

Comment: @achillehui Thanks, I was thrown off by the bound of 90.