# The sum of the reciprocals of the integers written without a digit "2" in base 10

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S$ be the set of integers without a 2 in the decimal representation. Does the sum $\sum_{n \in S} n^{-1}$ converge?

I'm not entirely sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: This sort of series is known as [Kempner series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kempner_series). Look at answers and refs [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1037279/59379), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/512262/59379), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/184045/59379) and [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/387/59379). I'm sure I've missed a few more....

Comment: "I'm not entirely sure how to approach this problem." So, does that mean you are partially sure how to approach the problem? What part of approaching the problem are you sure about?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: how many such numbers have $d$ digits?  Estimate the sum of the reciprocals of those numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to achille hui and Robert Israel for pointing me in the correct direction. I'll answer my own question since I've figured out how to do this.

There are $9^{d-1}8$ integers of length $d$ that don't have a single number (e.g. integers without 2 in the decimal representation). The smallest of these is $10^{d-1}$, so their reciprocals are bounded above by $9^{d-1}8 \times 10^{1-d} = 8 \times (9/10)^{d-1}$. Summing over $d$, this is a geometric series that converges to 80.

Therefore the original sum converges.

Comment: Right on. We don't really care to what that geometric series converges though, but only that it converges.